# Ubuntu stuck at boot

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, boot

My Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck at the boot. The screen becomes black and the only visible thing is a small underscore on top. I cannot enter the command line. I think I might have screwed something with systemd. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you still access the bootloader (usually GRUB), or does the system get stuck even before that? If you can, edit the boot entry to add `systemd.unit=emergency.target` to the end of the `linux ...` line. If you cannot access the bootloader, your boot disk may have failed: try booting the system from some live Linux media and check the health of the disk.

Comment: Can you provide more detail, such as when it gets stuck? Does anything happen first, such as the BIOS power on screen? Does the bootloader start up? And so on. Also, what have you tried? Have you tried booting a LiveCD?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? What video card/chip? If UEFI press Escape key after UEFI/BIOS screen but before grub menu to get grub menu. If BIOS press & hold shift key to get grub menu. New systems should be UEFI with gpt partitioning. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Is the small underscore blinking?  For me, that happened a couple of days ago when I screwed up my `nvidia-driver` stuff and the x-server failed to start.  You can use `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F5` (or almost any of the F-keys) to switch to a different TTY and get access to a terminal.  From there you can recover whatever got screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

- This normally is caused by some issues either in grub config file or some issues with initramfs. So try to boot with other kernels (if it is there).
- Remove "quiet splash" from kernel commandline(grub) and try "nosplash debug"(if needed) which will provide more verbose of booting.